# Get url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I am trying to do. I'm trying to pass the drop down selected value to my controller.

I have a drop down menu like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("divs", null, "--Select--", new {id="divs", onchange="SelectedIndexChanged(this.value);" })&nbsp;&nbsp;

@section Scripts 
{
  <script>

     function SelectedIndexChanged(divs) {   
         document.getElementById('divs').href = 
                  '/Controllers/MyFunction?divs=' + divs;
     }

  </script>
}
```

in my controller, I am trying to get the value divs:

```
public MyFunction (string divs)
{
    string type = Request.QueryString["divs"];
    MessageBox.Show(type); //this is empty
}
```

Comment: 1. What's the question? 2. Why are you trying to get `divs` both as an argument and from the query string? 3. `messagebox.show()type;` is invalid. 4. What do you mean by `this is empty`?

Comment: Setting `href` on a `select` (which is what `@Html.DropDownList` makes) is nonsense.

Comment: @Menew Sorry, it's not making sense yet. *What do you need to do?*

Comment: To answer what you're trying to ask, though: given that everything else is set up right, `MyFunction?divs=something` is a perfectly valid way to call `MyFunction(string divs)` and give that `divs` a value of `something`. You don't need to use `Request.QueryString`. The problem at this point would seem to be that you're never actually calling that URL.

Comment: @Andre well if you read from above, i am trying to send my drop down menu to my controller, so i am using javascript for the onchange event. however, the url doesn't get redirected. the value is coming as empty.

Comment: @Menew Is `MyFuntion` an action? It has no return type, so I can't tell

Comment: @Andre yes it is public FileContentResult MyFunction(string divs)

Comment: @Menew Can you provide some feedback on my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Typing this from my head compiler so it might not be quite right but should get you closer.

```
@Html.DropDownList("divs", null, "--Select--", new { id="divs"})

@section Scripts 
{
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#divs").change(function() {
      val selected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyFunction", "Controller", new { divs = selected })',
        dataType: 'json',
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyFunction (string divs)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're trying to do. It's not a complete solution, you have to work it out.

Note: I'm using jQuery for the javascript part.

Action:

```
public JsonResult MyFunction (string divs)
{
    return Json(divs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
$(function() {
    $("#divs").changed(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/controllers/myfunction'
            , cache: false
            , type: 'GET'
            , dataType: 'json'
            , data: { divs = $(this).val() }
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

You can remove that javascript binding from the dropdown declaration.

Comment: i actually got it working by just calling this: window.top.location.href='http://'+document.domain+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value right in the options selected. thanks anyways.